# Is there way to save google maps for offline iphone without jailbreak

Tags: iphone, gps, google-maps

I've iPhone 3Gs and want to **download Google maps to use them offline with GPS**.

So is there a good app do that for me ?

Note: i don't want to jailbreak my iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

No, nor will you find one (in the official App Store). Storing the image tiles breaches Google's data licence. There are a bunch of apps that use OpenStreetMap, which has a more liberal licence.

Comment: As Stephen noted, it's against the licensing terms. Last time I looked they allowed for some small images like they have next to directions, but other than that you're out of luck (and they definitely don't respond to GPS).

Answer (score 1):

## NO.

You can't download stuff like that for offline without a jailbreak.

Comment: You can, actually. http://modmyi.com/cydia/package.php?id=10733

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not very helpful but some Android phones do have this capability.

http://www.htc.com/www/product/desirehd/overview.html for example.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend

Offline+Maps 
https://itunes.apple.com/app/offline+maps/id502648393

or

City maps 2 Go
https://itunes.apple.com/app/city-maps-2go/id327783342